# Alphatbetically sort MYSQL results ascending, but not sorting 'The' as a T?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there was a quick way to sort like this?

Imagine the results being book titles or movie titles etc, i dont want such titles that start with the word 'THE' sorting as a T, i want it to sort as the next word on.. For instance "The Hound of the Baskervilles" would sort as "Hound of the Baskervilles, The" so would be returned as an H and not a T.

Thanks.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois . . . Although almost a duplicate, the answers here are much better than most of the answers for that question -- including the two top ranked answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a sort that I am aware of that would do that... however it is very easy to action by making a new column, ensuring that doesn't start with "the " and sort by that...

```
SELECT title,TRIM(LEADING 'the ' FROM LOWER(title)) AS title_without_the 
FROM books_and_movies
ORDER BY title_without_the
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

```
order (case when title like 'The %' then lower(substr(Title, 5))
            else lower(title)
       end)
```

The `lower()` is to handle case-sensitive collations, so it is not always necessary.

Comment: LOWER isn't required when using LIKE because in MySQL, SQL patterns are case-insensitive by default

Comment: Thanks for the help guys ;)